# Previous / next page links using Laravel

Tags: laravel-4, navigation

I am developing a small portfolio site and i am stuck for a second.

So users are allowed to upload their sort them ( with [jQuery sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) )

So when other users view his / her portfolio it is displayed by sort order, and when you click on the image it shows a big image.

Here i would like a Previous / next navigation so people can navigate.

It works but i have a problem, so currently in my database the image with the 8 is the last one, but because the images are displayed by sort order, and the image with id 8 which is the last is in the fifth place it stops returning the next id, and it should be there.

Here is what i tried.

**Controller**

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $photo = $this->photo->find($id);

        if(is_null($photo)) return App::abort('404');

        $previous = $this->photo->where('id', '<', $photo->id)->where('user_id', '=', $photo->user_id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();

        $next = $this->photo->where('id', '>', $photo->id)->where('user_id', '=', $photo->user_id)->orderBy('sort', 'ASC')->first();

        $this->layout->title = "Saját képek";
        $this->layout->content = View::make('photo::show')
                                 ->with('photo', $photo)
                                 ->with('previous', $previous)
                                 ->with('next', $next);
    }
```

**View**

```
<div class="ui page grid">
    <div class="ui grid">
        <div class="wide column">
            <div class="ui segment">
                <div class="photo-viev-nav">
                    @if(!empty($previous->id))
                        <a href="{{ URL::to( 'portfolio/pic/' . $previous->id ) }}" class="ui tiny button"><i class="ui left icon"></i> Vissza </a>
                    @endif
                        <strong>{{ $photo->user->name() }} potfóliója</strong>
                    @if(!empty($next))
                        <a href="{{ URL::to( 'portfolio/pic/' . $next->id ) }}" class="ui tiny button"> Következő  <i class="ui right icon"></i></a>
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="photo-view">
                    {{ HTML::image($photo->photoOriginal(), '', array('class' => 'ui huge image')) }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The second i tried is this query

```
$previous = $this->photo->where('id', '<', $photo->id)->where('user_id', '=', $photo->user_id)->orderBy('sort', 'ASC')->max('id');

$next = $this->photo->where('id', '>', $photo->id)->where('user_id', '=', $photo->user_id)->orderBy('sort', 'ASC')->min('id');
```

But the problem with this it ignores the sort order

Could please someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experimented more, and i was a bit silly, instead of focusing on the id i needed to focus on the sort order and get the id's based on that way

Correct query

```
$previous = $this->photo->where('sort', '<', $photo->sort)->where('user_id', '=', $photo->user_id)->orderBy('', 'DESC')->first();

$next = $this->photo->where('sort', '>', $photo->sort)->where('user_id', '=', $photo->user_id)->orderBy('sort', 'ASC')->first();
```